# Same class in the Grothendieck ring, different $\pi_2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-rings

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Are there two connected smooth projective $k$-schemes that have the same class in the Grothendieck ring and have non-isomorphic etale $\pi_2$ groups?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the original user has been deleted or deleted their account and there is no point speaking back into a void